# Selenium Webdriver Python select a dropdown error local variable element referenced before assignment

Tags: css, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a drop down element but I am getting the error

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\OperationsPage_TestCase.py", line 59, in test_add_and_run_clean_process
    process_lists_page.click_select_a_preview_to_import_configuration_from_dropdown_from_clean_task_tab(Globals.datapreview_crm_name)
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\operations.py", line 113, in click_select_a_preview_to_import_configuration_from_dropdown_from_clean_task_tab
    select = (Select(self.get_element(By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[10]/span/select')))
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\Pages\base.py", line 31, in get_element
    return element
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'element' referenced before assignment
```

My method implementation is:

```
def click_select_a_preview_to_import_configuration_from_dropdown_from_clean_task_tab(self, data_preview_name):
    #select = Select(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Select a data preview to import configuration from")]/preceding::span[1]//../span//../select')
    #select = (Select(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Select a data preview to import configuration from")]/preceding::span[1]//../span//../select')))))
    #select = (Select(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[10]/span/select')))))
    select = (Select(self.get_element(By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[10]/span/select')))
    print select.options
    print [o.text for o in select.options] # these are string-s
    select.select_by_visible_text(str(data_preview_name))
    return self
```

get_element implementation is:

```
    # returns the element if found
    def get_element(self, how, what):
        # params how: By locator type
        # params what: locator value
        try:
            element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            print what
            print "Element not found "
            print e
        return element
```

The method to call the drop down from the TestCase class is:

```
process_lists_page.click_select_a_preview_to_import_configuration_from_dropdown_from_clean_task_tab("Selenium_LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE")
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="operations_add_process_list_tab_groups_tab_standard_1">
    <span/>
    <span>
        <span class="" title="" style="font-weight:bold;">Select a data  preview to import configuration from</span>
    </span>
    <span>
    <span/>
    <span/>
    <span/>
    <span/>
    <span/>
    <span>
    <span class="" title="None" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;">
        <select tabindex="-1">
            <option selected="selected" value="None">None</option>
            <option value="CRMINVALID_07102015">CRMINVALID_07102015</option>
            <option value="LADEMO_crm2_Chrome">LADEMO_crm2_Chrome</option>
            <option value="LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE_CHROME">LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE_CHROME</option>
            <option value="LADEMO_ESCR_DO_NO_CHANGE_CHROME">LADEMO_ESCR_DO_NO_CHANGE_CHROME</option>
            <option value="Lademo_odb_Data">Lademo_odb_Data</option>
            <option value="MegaOne_07102015">MegaOne_07102015</option>
            <option value="riazNoQuotesUTF8">riazNoQuotesUTF8</option>
            <option value="Selenium_LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE">Selenium_LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE</option>
            <option value="Selenium_LADEMO_ESCR_DONOTCHANGE">Selenium_LADEMO_ESCR_DONOTCHANGE</option>
            <option value="Selenium_LADEMO_ORCHARD_DONOTCHANGE">Selenium_LADEMO_ORCHARD_DONOTCHANGE</option>
            <option value="test">test</option>
            <option value="_CRM_DONOTCHANGE">_CRM_DONOTCHANGE</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Why am i getting the error?  Is it a race condition, the element is not yet visible?
I have tried using WebDriverWait, I get the same error.

From the drop down I would like to select the value "Selenium_LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE"

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "private" method to find the element.

According to its [description](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=find_element#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element):

> **find_element(by='id', value=None)**
>
> ‘Private’ method used by the find_element_by_* methods.
>
> Usage: Use the corresponding find_element_by_* instead of this.

Try changing:

```
element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
```

For:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(value=what)
```

Comment: That method get_element is in my base class.  i am inheriting from it.  My other test cases works with this when i call get_element.  My class header is class OperationsPage(BasePage):

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it to work now.  I used the following XPATH

```
//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_tab_groups_tab_standard_1"]//select
```

The WebDriverWait code is:

```
select = Select(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_tab_groups_tab_standard_1"]//select'))))
```

There is only 1 drop down below the div id.  //select will find the drop down from anywhere inside the div id tag.  If the structure changes this will still work.